Questions about a Lemma in the proof of the soul theorem
Here is a Lemma in the proof of the soul theorem in Petersen's Riemannian Geometry:
Lemma 12.4.8. Let $(M, g)$ have $\sec \geq 0$. If $A \subset M$ is totally convex, then the distance function $r: A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $r(x)=|x \partial A|$ is concave on $A$. When $\mathrm{sec}>0$, then any maximum for $r$ is unique.
In the proof of this lemma, he first fixed $q \in\operatorname{int} A$ and chose $p \in \partial A$ such that $|p q|=|q \partial A|$.Then he selected a segment $\overline{p q}$ in $A$ and using exponential coordinates to create a hypersurface $H$ which is the image of the hyperplane perpendicular to $\overrightarrow{p q}$. Let $f(x)=|x H|$ we can see that $f$ is a support function from above for $r(x)=|x \partial A|$ at all points on $\overline{p q}$ ($r≤f,r(p')=f(p')$). He then stated that $f$ is smooth at $p^{\prime}$ except possibly when $p^{\prime}=q$ and showed that Hess$f\leq 0$ at $p^{\prime} \neq q$.
$\mathbf{Question 1}$: Why is $f$ smooth at $p^{\prime}$ except possibly when $p^{\prime}=q$? In general case where $H$ is a properly embedded submanifold I only know $f$ has one-sided directional derivative and smooth in a small neighborhood of $H$. I think this is relevant to exponential coordinates,but I don't know how.
$\mathbf{Question 2}$: Why is $|x \partial A|$ concave in a neighborhood of $p^{\prime}$ as we only know there is a support function $f$ from above such that Hess$f\leq 0$ at $p^{\prime}$?
Any suggestions will be welcomed!

I have found that my third question below is unnecessary:
$\mathbf{Question 3}$: Does weakly strict concave imply strict concave？Here a function $g:R\to R$ is weakly strict concave means that for every $x$ we have a strict concave function $h$ support from above in a neighborhood of $x$ (with $h(x)=g(x)$).
this is because to show maximum of $r$ is unique when sec$>0$, we only need to show that weakly strict concave function cannot be constant on an open interval, which is obvious.

It's probably worth looking at other expositions of the proof and maybe even the original paper.

Sorry for my recklessness. I have realized that some of my question is unnecessary and I have tried to make my question shorter and more clear.

Why is it called the soul theorem?

@Mike this is just a lemma prepared for the proof of the soul theorem. The statement of the  soul theorem can be found in Wikipedia.

I think I have worked out a proof of this lemma. Basically I followed the idea of Petersen, with some changes to make sure the argument can go through.
Firstly, we choose $H$ as a hypersurface in the segment domain of $p$ such that the second fundamental form of $H$ is negative at $p$ and $|xH|\geq r(x)$.
Secondly, instead of $|xH|$ we let $f(x)=|{\exp^{\perp}}^{-1}(x)|$. Here as $M$ is complete, we can restrict the exponential map onto normal bundle $T^{\perp}N$, that is, map $\exp^{\perp}:T^{\perp}N\to M$. Using index form as in exercise 6.7.24, we can see that $\exp^{\perp}$ is nonsingular for every $p'\neq q\in\overline{pq}$, thus $\exp^{\perp}$ is a diffeomorphism onto a neighborhood $U$ of $\overline{pq}\backslash\{q\}$, which justifies our new definition for function $f$.
Using the same argument as Petersen we can see that Hess$f(E,E)<0$ at $p'$ for $E$ orthogonal to $\nabla f$ (because initial value is negative and derivative is nonpositive). This implies that Hess$f(E,E)<0$ for $E$ orthogonal to $\nabla f$ in a neighborhood of $p'$, so $f$ is both smooth and concave in a neighborhood of $p'$, which solves my question 1 and 2.
Thirdly, when $f$ is not smooth at $q$, we define the same $H'$ as Petersen (here we should let $H'$ sufficiently small so that $H'\subset U$). Then we want to prove $g(x):=\left|p p^{\prime}\right|+\left|x H^{\prime}\right|$ is a support function for $|x H|$. In this case we can select $z \in H^{\prime}$ such that $|x H|\leq |z H|+\left|x H^{\prime}\right|$ and only need to prove $|z H| \leq\left|p p^{\prime}\right|$ for each $z \in H^{\prime}$, which can be done using the same way in the text. Recall that from the text, Hess$\left|x H^{\prime}\right|\leq 0$ at $q$, so we have show that $r(x)$ is weakly concave.
Fourthly, let's deal with the case $\sec>0$. Let
$$
\phi:[0, \infty) \rightarrow[0, \infty)\\
 x\mapsto \sqrt{x+1}-1,
$$
we can see that $\phi$ is strictly concave and increasing. Consider $\phi\circ f\circ\gamma$ for a geodesic $\gamma$ passing $p'$, we want to show it is strict concave around $0$.
We have
$$(\phi\circ f\circ\gamma)''=\phi''g(\nabla f,\gamma')^2+\psi'{\rm Hess} f(\gamma',\gamma')\leq 0$$
if this equals $0$, then $g(\nabla f,\gamma')={\rm Hess} f(\gamma',\gamma')=0$, which is impossible from step two. Similarly consider $\phi\circ g\circ\gamma$ for a geodesic $\gamma$ passing $q$, we can again see it is strict concave around $0$, because from $\sec>0$ we have Hess$g(E,E)<0$ for $E$ orthogonal to $\nabla g$ at $q$.
Now we have showed that $\phi\circ r\circ\gamma$ is weakly strict concave for every geodesic $\gamma$, from this we can see it's maximum point is unique.
